# PHP line parsed into separate objects

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a line of code in my wordpress widget that outputs from an RSS feed:

```
<?php echo $entry->title ?>
```

and when displayed it looks like:

> $220,000 :: 504 Freemason St, Unit 2B, Norfolk VA, 23510

or

> $274,900 :: 1268 Bells Road, Virginia Beach VA, 23454

What is the easiest way to break this up into different objects?

For example, I'd like to have the price, street name, and city state zip in different objects.  The problem is that some of the addresses have unit numbers and it's complicating things.  Below is an example of how I would like it to work:

```
<?php echo $entry->price ?>
<?php echo $entry->street ?>
<?php echo $entry->citystatezip ?>
```

> $220,000
>   504 Freemason St, Unit 2B
>   Norfolk VA, 23510

or

> $274,900
>   1268 Bells Road
>   Virginia Beach VA, 23454

Comment: Post the exact output of `$entry->title`.

Comment: How is the `title` being generated?  Maybe these individual values already exist elsewhere.

Comment: The examples I showed are the exact output... unless I don't understand your question.  It's the Title tag from my RSS feed.

Comment: @Rocket I wish they did.  I already checked for that.

Comment: Here is an example of the feed the widget is parsing: http://idx.diversesolutions.com/Feed/RSS/15054836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very crude regex that seems able to parse your string.  I'm not the best with regexes, but it seems to work.

```
/^(\$(?:\d{1,3},?)*) :: (\d* [\w\s,\d]*), ([\w\s]* \w{2}, \d{5})$/
```

Use this with `preg_match`; the 1st group is the price, the 2nd is the address, and 3rd is the city/state/zip.

Example:

```
<?php
$ptn = '/^(\$(?:\d{1,3},?)*) :: (\d* [\w\s,\d]*), ([\w\s]* \w{2}, \d{5})$/';
if(preg_match($ptn, $entry->title, $match) === 1){
    $price = $match[1];
    $street = $match[2];
    $citystatezip = $match[3];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a regular expression , check http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Use f.e. `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )` which will give you array with strings if you use correct delimiter

Answer (score 0):

The code below will fill your $entry object as required:

```
$string = '$274,900 :: 1268 Bells Road, Virginia Beach VA, 23454';
$pricePart = explode('::', $string);
$addressPart = explode(',', $pricePart[1]);

$entry = new stdClass();
$entry->price = trim($pricePart[0]);

if ( count($addressPart) == 3 ) {
    $entry->street = trim($addressPart[0]);
    $entry->citystatezip = trim($addressPart[1]) . ', ' . trim($addressPart[2]);
} else {
    $entry->street = trim($addressPart[0]) . ', ' . trim($addressPart[1]);
    $entry->citystatezip = trim($addressPart[2]) . ', ' . trim($addressPart[3]);
}
```

**Updated answer to handle the unit bit**

**Update: changed array names, I hate $array.. names.. even if its just a mockup**

(Note: this code isn't the prettiest, but its ment to give a base to work on. It should be cleaned up and improved a bit)

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where there's a unit number for the address.

Comment: Well close enough anyways. You will have to check the length of $array2 before splitting street and citystatezip. Based on the length you can decide which parts are which.

Comment: Yes, thanks Damien, but my issue is also the properties that include unit numbers in the address and there is an extra comma.

Comment: Fixed some other small issues. Should pretty much work i guess. But adjust as needed.